# improve EditInOsm link

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

On a old v2.12 of OpenLayer, a link allow to edit the location in OpenStreetMap
but the [current code](https://github.com/osm-fr/presentoir-carte/blob/master/www/index.php#L167)

- include an unwanter &layer in the link
- doesn't allow the user to choice if he want to use iD or JOSM

before coding thoses improvements, 2 questions:

- does anyone have any advice on this ? I'm new to this :) or maybe I miss a plugin that have thoses features
- Do you think it's better to do the openlayer upgrade first or could I easily incorporate the code from the previous version into the current version?